# Balanced Mixing for Target Covariance

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a vector of i.i.d. random variables. Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a desired covariance matrix for which I like to determine mixing matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that

$$
var(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{C}.
$$

Now, this could be solved by the Cholesky or eigenvalue decomposition depending on the definiteness of $\mathbf{C}$. I am, however, interested in a *balanced* mixing matrix, i.e.,

$$
| a_{ij} | = |a_{ji}|
$$

The idea is that the resulting random variables are as mixed as possible. In contrary, if $\mathbf{A}$ is triangular (as from the Cholesky decomposition) at least one random variable is identical to the original which is undesired.

A numerical example: Let $$\mathbf{C} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
be the desired covariance matrix. Possible mixing matrices are 
$$\mathbf{A}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} / \sqrt{3} \textrm{ and } \mathbf{A}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf{A}_1^T \mathbf{A}_1 = \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{A}_2^T \mathbf{A}_2 = \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{A}_1$ is more balanced than $\mathbf{A}_2$.

What is a systematic method to find a balanced mixing matrix (such as $\mathbf{A}_1$) instead of an unbalanced mixing matrix (such as $\mathbf{A}_2$)?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts that might be helpful.

Let's say you can distill your balance criterion into an objective function $f(A)$. Once we find one viable matrix $A_0$, for example by Cholesky, all other matrices can be derived as $QA_0$ where $Q$ is orthogonal such that $Q^TQ=I$. Therefore your problem reduces to finding an orthogonal matrix that maximizes $f(QA_0)$. Depending on your function $f$, there might even be closed form expression for $Q$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The invariance under orthogonal transformation certainly helps. Are you aware of any terminology regarding the balance criterion which would aid literature search?